# How to prevent event firing after programmatically interacting with controls?

Tags: c#, user-interface, events, event-handling, controls

I have a CheckedBoxList. Also I have a `ItemCheck` event attached to it, so a fuction is executed after I checked an item. But the problem is, at one point in my program I need to programmatically check/uncheck items. And this action triggers the event function.

My guess is is also applies to other controls.

How can I prevent such behaviour? I need function to be run only when user interacts with it, not when I am doing something with control inside my app.

Comment: just put a flag that will only be true by onClick_Event.And use onChange_Event for check box status.A condition will decide if your changed item has been clicked or not! simple

Comment: Another option - custom control with overridden onevent using your logic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap all your changes to CheckedBoxList in a function and use that function everytime. The code may look something like this:

```
private void UpdateCheckedListBox() // You would need to add your parameters
{
    checkedListBox1.ItemCheck -= checkedListBox1_ItemCheck;
    // your changes to checked list box goes here
    checkedListBox1.ItemCheck += checkedListBox1_ItemCheck;
}
```

Comment: What is easier and natural to do? Setting a boolean flag or adding - removing event binding?. I agree explanation is required for downvoting. But are you the only one victim of this sort of ambush? God helps us all.

Comment: An answer to a question needs to meet its requirement. It may not be better but it can solve the OP's problem. If there is another way of doing something then I don't see any harm in letting someone know about it.

Comment: This gave me a grand idea!

Answer (score 3):

Use a flag

```
private bool _updating;

void CheckedBoxList_ItemCheck(sender object, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_updating)  return;

    // Execute item check code
}

void SomewhereElse()
{
    _updating = true;
    try {
        // programmatically check/uncheck items
    } finally {
        _updating = false;
    }
}
```

The try/finally statement ensures that the flag gets unset even if an exception should occur or if the try code block is left with `return` (or `break` within a loop).

Answer (score 1):

First create boolean variable at form level:

```
bool dontUpdate = false;
```

Then in your Checklist Itemcheck method, execute only if dontUpdate is false:

```
public void CheckedBoxList_ItemCheck(sender object, EventArgs e) {
    if (dontUpdate) return;
    //else execute
}
```

Now when checking items programmatically, set it to true:

```
void nativeUpdate(){
    dontUpdate = true;
    //Do your items check
    dontUpdate = false;
}
```

Whenever you need to check item/S programmatically, use nativeUpdate method.